# ImportError: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I am installing Tensor Flow 0.11 in a virtual environment. After installing using this command

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I get error on importing the library:

```
import tensorflow

ImportError: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String
```

Please tell how to resolve this. I have searched on the web and I got results relating to python using USC2 instead of USC4, but I could not resolve it.

**Update**: I installed miniconda and activated the conda enviroment. Then I carried on the installation of TensorFlow 0.11 in the conda environment and it successfully installed and gave no error on import tensorflow.

Comment: You need to recompile either Python or TensorFlow with the proper compiler options. Right now Python is configured to use UTF16 strings while TensorFlow is configured to use UCS4 strings.

Comment: Would you please explain the procedure to this, sorry i am unable to follow your solution.

Comment: I've never done it myself so I really can't help, I was hoping that someone else would come along and fill in the details. If you want to avoid this try switching to Python 3.3 or later.